# TSearchBox.OnKeyUp event ignores ENTER key in Delphi 11

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

When using a `TSearchBox` control in Delphi, I catch pressing the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key (13) to run a certain function. Simply by:

```pascal
If key = 13 then DoSomeThing;
```

After updating to Delphi 11, this doesn't work anymore. I can catch any character but not 13.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using VCL or FMX?

Comment: I am using VCL.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is intentional! Before Delphi 11, `TSearchBox` meant to handle `VK_RETURN` in its `KeyPress()` method, but failed to do so because it didn't even get that key. In Delphi 11, this has been fixed by having `TSearchBox` handle `CM_WANTSPECIALKEY`.

The corresponding QP report is [RSP-30203: TSearchBox must implement CM_WANTSPECIALKEY](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-30203)

Comment: Which means you should now be able to use the [`TSearchBox.OnInvokeSearch`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.WinXCtrls.TSearchBox.OnInvokeSearch) event when `ENTER` is pressed, as originally documented: "*If `SearchIndicator` is `sbiText`, `OnInvokeSearch` also occurs when the Enter key is pressed.*"

Comment: Thank you @Uwe, that was very helpful. I have modified my code by removing the handling of "pressing the Enter key" from the OnKeyUp to the OnKeyPressed event. This event catches the Enter key, like OnKeyUp did before. May thanks, and to Remy of course.
By the way, I did not understand what to do with CM_WANTSPECIALKEY.

Comment: @JGMS There is nothing *you* have to do with `CM_WANTSPECIALKEY`. `TSearchBox` handles `CM_WANTSPECIALKEY` internally in order to receive `ENTER` presses.